# CompletableFuture with variable length Runnable tasks running asynchronously

Tags: java-8

to my knowledge, of now the following api is missing:

```
CompletableFuture future = null;
List<String> emails = ...
for(String email: emails) {
    future = future.runAsync(new SendEmailTask(email));
}
```

or

```
List<CompletableFuture> runAsync(List<Runnable> tasks);
```

When I see its doc or tutorial, it feels like a user needs to know how many tasks there is, and coding 'statically' accordingly. So I still use `executors.invokeAll` for variable length lists of tasks. Is there a method to use `CompletableFuture` to do this?

Comment: Are you sure that `SendEmailTask` is a `Runnable`? A `Callable` would make more sense, especially when you say that it works with `ExecutorService.invokeAll`…

Comment: I was thinking `Runnable` when using `CompletableFuture`  Now thanks to your answer, I know there is an easy way to cast `Runnable` to `Callable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `SendEmailTask` truly is a `Runnable`, you can’t pass a list of them to `ExecutorService.invokeAll`, you’d need a conversion. The code needed to do this doesn’t differ significantly from the code to do this with `CompletableFuture`:

```
    ExecutorService es = …

    List<Future<Object>> list = es.invokeAll(emails.stream()
        .map(s -> Executors.callable(new SendEmailTask(s)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

```
    List<Future<Void>> list = emails.stream()
        .map(s -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(new SendEmailTask(s)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If these futures do not return any result and you’re just interested in being able to wait for the completion, you can use

```
CompletableFuture<?> f = CompletableFuture.allOf(emails.stream()
    .map(s -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(new SendEmailTask(s)))
    .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new));
```

The `CompletableFuture` will be completed when all jobs have been completed and it will be completed exceptionally if any of the tasks failed. However, if multiple tasks failed, you will only be able to inspect one of the exceptions.